# How to apply a pre-deployment gate to check the release execution current time vs the scheduled time in ServiceNow?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, servicenow, change-management

How to apply a pre-deployment gate in Azure DevOps to deploy an application using release pipelines. The gate should effectively check the current time vs the scheduled time in ServiceNow. If the current time is greater than or equal to the scheduled time in the Change Request then the gate should pass and the release pipeline should start executing.

I need a starting idea on how to setup this. I already have a Service Connection that connects to ServiceNow.

Comment: You are using ["Classic release pipelines"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops)? From ServiceNow can you fire a script or event? You might consider adding an automated pre-deployment approval. When the scheduled time arrives in ServiceNow an automated approval is applied to 'release' the release pipeline.

Comment: Another approach would be to a add a ["Scheduled release trigger"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#scheduled-release-triggers). You can set up a schedule for the release for, as an example, every hour. The first step in the pipeline would be to check if the release can proceed based on the information in ServiceNow. Essentially you would be polling and the schedule trigger would define the polling frequency.

Comment: Appreciate your help @Jonathan Dodds; I am trying to automate the process entirely so anyone who creates a Change Request won't need to do any manual steps. I need this script to be placed at a gate level so that it is controlled by the automation.

Comment: @Enig, are you following doc [Integrate with ServiceNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/servicenow?view=azure-devops) with extension [ServiceNow Change Management extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-servicenowchangerequestmanagement) in the release pre-deployment gate? Do you want to create the change request with schedule time via devops? or using existing change reqeust in service now?

Comment: @Enig I wasn't suggesting a manual deployment approval. There is an API for updating approvals. "I need this script to be placed at a gate level ..." - There is not a trigger type that will run a custom script to determine if the trigger should fire. i.e. you can't place the script at the gate level.

Comment: The ServiceNow extension that @wadezhou-MSFT mentions adds a release gate type specific to ServiceNow. That seems like the way to go.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Thanks I am using the extension, however, I have the sample time interval set to 5 mins and after every 5 mins a new Change is created in ServiceNow. This is not effective. Not sure how to stop it.

Comment: @Enig, what's the timeout value on `Evaluation options` setting on the gate? try to increase it so that the it can complete the try. Make sure your request can complete. Can refer to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops#gate-evaluation-flow-examples) for more details.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT The timeout is set for 30 minutes, however, a developer can request the Change Request (CR) to be scheduled days ahead of time. For example: a developer is requesting CR after 5 business days on a Friday after hours until then the gate should evaluate in specified time intervals for the same CR rather than creating one in each sample interval. Also, is there a logic to apply in gates to check for scheduled time in ServiceNow vs the current time and the pass gate if it's within the change window?

Comment: @Enig, the extension only supports two actions: create a new change request or using existing change request, you can use existing change request to query the scheduled time, try `advanced Success criteria` to compare with system.time.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT I am using the exact same extension with a sample interval of 15 minutes. The predeployment gate creates a new Change Request every 15 minutes. That's a degraded process, I guess.